# Accessing link function from ngView?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-routing

Beginner to Angular, I may be phrasing this incorrectly but I don't know how else to describe it.

When a route change occurs like this

```
.when('/manage/users', {
    templateUrl: 'Angular/manage/users/overview.html',
    controller: 'usersCtrl'
    }
})
```

Is there anyway to access `compile` or `link` functions for the loading template as if it was a directive?

I'd like to include a loading animation on the route to be loaded INSIDE the template but I don't see a way to access the template as if it was a directive(where i would usually use `link`)

**EDIT: Example of what I'm trying to do**

When the above route is invoked

**overview.html**

```
<div ng-controller="usersCtrl" class="listPane">
 <div class="loader">Loading...</div> <!--Relevant Div I want to control-->
    <div ng-repeat="group in listGroups">
        <div class="tile-group max">
            <div class="tile-group-title"><a>{{group.title}}</a></div>
                <div listview items="group.items"></div>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller does an async GET to get a list of users

```
app.controller('usersCtrl', ['$scope','companyService', function($scope, companyService){

$scope.listGroups = {title:'All Users',
                     items:[]};

$scope.listAsyncAnimate = true; //variable I would like to use to control showing or hiding loading div

$scope.$watch('listGroups', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.listGroups = newVal;

});
    companyService.getUsers(1).then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.listAsyncAnimate = false; //turn off loading div after list has been returned
        $scope.listGroups = [{
            title: 'All Users',
            items:  Utility.userlistToMetroList(data)
        }];
    });
}]);
```

In other directives I use the above controllre functionality ALONG WITH watching the variable to control visibility from `link`, which I don't have access to when I'm doing a route change to a template(`overview.html`):

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {

var loader = $(element).find('.loader');

scope.$watch('listAsyncAnimate', function(newVal, oldVal){
           if(newVal)
           {
               loader.spin('small');
               loader.removeClass('ng-hide');
           }
            else
           {
               loader.addClass('ng-hide');
           }
        });
 }
```

Comment: Can you please write a pseudo code of how you want the route definition to look like?

Comment: I've added an example of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: why use `ng-contoller` if you already define it in the `$routeProvider`? Please make your whole explanation more clear

Comment: sorry I Should have removed the resolve function, it was irrelevant to the example(I use it for other functionality). Can I use resolve to achieve what I'm doing? I was under the assumption that content would not render until resolve completed its operations, would that not defeat the point of making the call async?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want a linking function inside the route definition ? I can do that but It's probably better to go with simpler solution

Comment: Correct -- but only because I don't know another way to do what I'm doing. As I said I'm a beginner and Angular is still a struggle for me :) Any suggestions on how to achieve this using an alternative solution would be welcome!

Comment: I still cannot understand what you want to achieve yet I've solved what you asked

Comment: Thank you for your effort! This does solve my question however I think my problem lies in my poor understanding of Angular :) I think I need to re-think how I am structuring my directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/APlxVnbOhOqkFcnRuhu8?p=preview):

#### Just create a directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($route){
  return {  
    link: function(){
      var link = $route.current.link || angular.noop;
      link.apply(null,arguments);
    }
  }
})
```

#### And add it to `ngView`

```
<div ng-view my-directive></div>
```

#### now in your route defintion you have a link function:

```
.when('/manage/users', {
    templateUrl: 'Angular/manage/users/overview.html',
    controller: 'usersCtrl',
    link: function(scope,elm,attrs){
       // do your magic
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Won't the directive be blind to the template it is acting on though? I'd like the scope to be specific to the template being loaded to avoid cluttering the parent scope for all other directives loaded through ng-view.

Comment: `ng-view` creates new child scope for each template it loads. This directive will run with a different scope every time the route load a template.

Comment: But the scope variables I set in `myDirective` will be available to every directive that runs in ngView, no? I want the variables to be specific for that route. An example case being that I have three loaders on three seperate routes -- using this I would have access to all three loader variables even though I am only using one route(or a route not even related to). I want them to be contained(and manipulated) in the route they belong to -- but I don't want to have to create a new directive for each route to do it.